# ios objective c help with array please!

Tags: image, ios, uiimage, nsarray

im new to programming and im trying to make my first iphone app.  basically what my app needs to do is draw a random image from an array and output it to a UIImageView in a view.  it should be really simple but i cant find anywhere on the internet how to output the array to the uiimage

```
theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one.png",@"two.png",@"three.png",nil];
```

heres a basic code of the images.  any help would be greatly appreciated!!

also if you could explain any other details i might need.

Answer (score 3):

find a random array index using -

```
int randomArrIndex = arc4random() % [arr count];
```

then you can fetch image name from array with this index

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[arr objectAtIndex:randomArrIndex]];
```

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks so much i will try that as soon as i get home.

Comment: actually the code you told me isnt working,  its saying randomArrIndex isnt defined and  [arr objectAtIndex:randomArrIndex] isnt defined

Comment: `UIImageView *cardOutput = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:  [Array objectAtIndex:randomArrIndex]];
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one.png",@"two.png",@"three.png",nil];
    int randomArrayIndex = arc4random() % [Array count];
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
}`

is randomArrIndex a method i need to define?  im still confused sorry

Comment: @Saurabh is randomArrIndex a method i need to define?  im still confused sorry.  the book im reading to learn to program is called "sams teach yourself iphone aplication developtment in 24 hours" and it barely touches on arrays at all and google is no help.

Comment: randomArrIndex  is an integer I defined in answer as - int randomArrIndex = arc4random() % [arr count];
write this line in your code before using it

Comment: also you can't learn iPhone sdk in 24 hour.. download this book and read http://www.filesonic.in/file/809396551/McGraw.Hill.iOS.SDK.Programming.A.Beginners.Guide.Jan.2011.rar

Comment: read this also http://www.filesonic.in/file/115461132/Peachpit.Press.iPhone.Application.Development.for.iOS.4.Sep.2010.rar

Comment: read this for objective c http://www.filesonic.in/file/115444552/Addison.Wesley.Learning.ObjectiveC.2.0.Jul.2010.rar

Comment: it doesnt mean you learn it in 24 hours,  he just wrote the book with "hours" instead of "chapters" to be modern or something idk.  thanks for all the info and your time!  if i could i would upvote u alot lol

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one.png",@"two.png",@"three.png",nil];
    int randomArrayIndex = arc4random() % [arr count];
    UIImageView *cardOutput = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[arr objectAtIndex:randomArrayIndex]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}`   @Saurabh here is the new code, it has no errors but when i run it, it just breaks in the simulator.  i feel like this is really simple and im over thinking it or something.  is there anything else i need to do for it to work?